# What is more prevalent: SOCKS Proxy or HTTP Proxy?

Tags: proxy, http, socks

I am working on a project where we need to decide which proxy to support first. Later we will add support for the other proxy. Is either SOCKS proxy or HTTP proxy more prevalent? Does anyone have any statistics to support?

I am definitely out of my area of expertise, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think HTTP proxies are more prevalent; they're easier to set up and less general, so I think they get set up a lot more often than SOCKS proxies.  Also, HTTP proxies do autoconfigure kinds of things that I don't think SOCKs proxies do, so they're often in place without the users even knowing about it.

Just a guess, I have no real data... but would love to see some!

Comment: Thanks for the info. That is what I have heard. Would be nice if there were some hard data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a HTTP proxy for a college and can tell you from experience: **HTTP is your answer**. You want to support it first, because it's used more widely. Also, if you support HTTPS (and therefor CONNECT argument for HTTP Proxy) you can delay Socks a bit. Most times its just the "kids" (be they 20 or 50yrs old) who want to connect with their messaging servers (ICQ/AOL, Jabber, ...) and this can be easily solved if you can configure CONNECT to different ports. Additionally, you should be able to supply a PAC-File from your software, makes life for your clients easier.

IF you support HTTP and code the stuff yourself, please look at ICP and using Cache Peers so people can use some Squid for caching too :-)